# What is the proof for the commutant lifting theorem by Sz-Nagy and Foias?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Citing Wikipedia, the statement of the [commutant lifting theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutant_lifting_theorem) is as follows:

> The commutant lifting theorem states that if $T$ is a contraction on a Hilbert space $H$, $U$ is its minimal unitary dilation acting on some Hilbert space $K$ (which can be shown to exist by [Sz.-Nagy's dilation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sz.-Nagy%27s_dilation_theorem)), and $R$ is an operator on $H$ commuting with $T$, then there is an operator $S$ on $K$ commuting with $U$ such that $$R T^n = P_H S U^n \vert_H \; \forall n \geq 0,$$ and $$\Vert S \Vert = \Vert R \Vert.$$ In other words, an operator from the commutant of $T$ can be "lifted" to an operator in the commutant of the unitary dilation of $T$.

I tried to find the proof for this theorem online, but I wasn't able to do so.

Do you maybe know where I could find it?

Comment: Could you also provide a link to the Wikipedia page referenced in your question?

Comment: @Aweygan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutant_lifting_theorem

Comment: Maybe the proof is out there somewhere, but you can't find it on Google, because instead of typing it up in search-engine-accessible text, it only exists as a screenshot. Isn't it annoying when people do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me quickly type out the proof given in Paulsen's book [*"Completely Bounded Maps and Operators Algebras"*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Completely_Bounded_Maps_and_Operator_Alg/VtSFHDABxMIC?hl=en&gbpv=1) on p.66 (Theorem 5.8):

> *Proof.* By scaling we may assume that $\|R\|=1$. Hence, by Ando's dilation theorem${}^1$
> there exists commuting unitaries $U_1$, $U_2$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal K_1$ containing $\mathcal H$
> such that $T^nR^m = P_{\mathcal H}U^n_1U_2^m|_{\mathcal H}$. Let $\mathcal K$ be the closed linear span of vectors
> of the form $U^n_1h$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, $h\in\mathcal H$. Then $\mathcal K$ is a reducing subspace for $U_1$, and
> $U = P_{\mathcal K}U_1|_{\mathcal K}$ is the minimal unitary dilation of $T$.
> Relative to $\mathcal K_1 = \mathcal K\oplus \mathcal K^\perp$ we have operator matrices
> $$
> U1 =\begin{pmatrix}U&0\\0&V\end{pmatrix},
> U2 =\begin{pmatrix}S&B\\C&D\end{pmatrix}\,.
> $$
> Since $U_1$ and $U_2$ commute, it follows that $U$ and $S$ commute and that
> $P_{\mathcal K}U_2U_1^n|_{\mathcal K}=SU^n$. Thus
> $$
>  P_{\mathcal H}SU^n|_{\mathcal H}=P_{\mathcal H}U_2U_1^n|_{\mathcal H}=RT^n \,.
> $$
> Finally, $1\leq\|R\|\leq\|S\|\leq\|U_2\|=1$ and so $\|R\|=\|S\|$.$\quad\square$

---

${}^1$: Ando's dilation theorem states that, given commuting contractions $T_1,T_2$ on a Hilbert space $\mathcal H$, there exists a Hilbert space $\mathcal K$ that contains $\mathcal H$ as a subspace, and commuting unitaries $U_1$, $U_2$ on $\mathcal K$, such that $$T_1^nT_2^m=P_{\mathcal H}U_1^nU_2^m|_{\mathcal H}$$ for all nonnegative integers $n,m$, cf. Thm. 5.5 in Paulsen's book.